# How to vertical space blank under <li> bullet background?

Tags: css, xhtml

This is css

```
li { background: transparent url(bullet-arrow.png) no-repeat left 4px; 
     padding-left: 10px; 
     list-style-image: none; 
     list-style-position: outside; 
     list-style-type: none; }
```

this is current output

[alt text http://shup.com/Shup/382212/11061275219-My-Desktop.png](http://shup.com/Shup/382212/11061275219-My-Desktop.png)

I need in this format

[alt text http://shup.com/Shup/382214/11061275414-My-Desktop.png](http://shup.com/Shup/382214/11061275414-My-Desktop.png)

Comment: What you want to have should be default behaviour since a li has a default display of list-item. Is it possible that there's some more css active?

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with this CSS declaration. Perhaps you want to have a look at the HTML using Firebug, Dragonfly or a similar tool?

Comment: can't see pics I'm afraid - ascii art?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just an idea... could you please try to set `display:block` (or, maybe, `display:inline-block`) for your `li`?

Comment: make sure the UL and the LIs are display block. Then it should work

Comment: the LI should have display:list-item, not block. http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: but i'm using background image in `li`

Comment: @oezi - problem solved by giving 1display:block1 to `li a {}`

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
li
{
  list-style-image:url('bullet-arrow.gif');
  list-style-position: outside;
}
```

(I submitted to early and then had to edit. Sorry!)